# Setting Up Easy First React Project

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, file, babeljs

I am having trouble setting up my first, extremely simple, React project. The root div is showing up on my screen, but the Greeting object (Hello world) is not.

Here is the HTML:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet"d type"text/css" href="re.css" />
<html>
<div id="root"></div>
</html>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel">
class Greeting extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<p>Hello world</p>);
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(
    <Greeting />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
</script>
```

Here is the CSS (not important):

```
 #root {
    width: 40%;
    height: 300px;
    margin-top: 3em;
    left: 30%;
    position: absolute;
    border: 3px solid black;

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

Thank you!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qmx96t4a/
Your code works fine, anyway have you tried create-react-app ? https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CePz4YE9hrE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems the html structure, you should wrap all content inside , like this,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" d type "text/css" href="re.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
            class Greeting extends React.Component {
                render() {
            return (<p>Hello world</p>);
        }
    }
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Greeting />,
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the answer!! I can't bump it up but others please do. Thanks so much!